# multi-tenant admin consent fails with "AADSTS90094"

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-authentication

I have the following setup:

- 2 tenants, `T-1` and `T-2`
- A multi-tenant app `A` registered in `T-1`.

  - It requires admin consent for the Graph API
  - In the manifest, I have `"availableToOtherTenants": true` and `"signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount"`
- I have an admin user `U-2` for `T-2`.
- `U-2` is invited to `T-1` as a guest and accepts.
- `U-2` attempts to provide admin consent for the app in `T-1` (`A`) via the url `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${T-1 guid}/adminconsent?${params}`

At this point, I get redirected to an error page with the following info:

---

`A-1` needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to grant permission to this app before you can use it.

- **Request Id**: bd83872a-aa37-440f-8a2e-82185f4f4300
- **Correlation Id**: 09219117-2532-4705-91f4-3447647feed0
- **Timestamp**: 2019-03-05T18:35:05Z
- **Message: AADSTS90094**: This operation can only be performed by an administrator. Sign out and sign in as an administrator or contact
  one of your organization's administrators.

---

FYI I had Advanced diagnostics enabled.

Any clues on what I could try next?

Comment: What are you sending for `{params}`? Are you signing into the Admin Consent with a Global Admin account from the tenant you are asking for consent from?

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for the quick reply. I **am** signing into the Admin Consent with a Global Admin account on tenant `T-2` - this is **not** the tenant where the app was registered (that is `T-1`). For `{params}`, I'm using: `client_id={my_client_id}&redirect_uri={my_callback_uri}&state={somestring}`.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur also, the app `A` is configured with the Application Permissions 
User.Read.All (under Graph API), which requires admin consent

Comment: Your app needs to obtain consent for each tenant from an admin _of that tenant_. Otherwise I could grant Admin Consent against my tenant and reset your password in yours. ;)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to use U-2 to do admin consent who is not an admin in T-1.

> U-2 attempts to provide admin consent for the app in T-1

Only admins in T-1 can provide admin consent in T-1. In your case that would be U-1 I believe.

Comment: This is correct. On the other hand, if it is desired that T-2 gets to use the app, then U-2 needs to do admin consent against T-2.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Chris. So does that mean there is no way to do multi-tenant admin consent? As in, `U-2` **must** be made an admin of `T-1` in order to give admin consent for `A`?

Comment: @chris you can do multi-tenant admin consent, but an admin in each tenant must do the consent. i.e. admin-1 in tenant-1 must consent and admin-2 in tenant-2 must do the consent.